# How to run a POST request programmatically in python with a GUI ? (spynner, webkit...)

Tags: python, user-interface, webkit, screen-scraping, spynner

I have a web site with [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) forms that I need to *scrape*. Instead of filling the `flash` forms, I would like to `POST` some keys/values to the URL that doesn't support `GET` requests.

I use [spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner) to interact with the site, and `spynner` can have a `GUI`, but my search on google, stackoverflow, spynner github and in the spynner module are unsuccessful.

If `spynner` can't do a `POST` request, maybe `gtk` or `qt` + `webkit` can do that ? Any real life code sample will be really appreciated.

Comment: Qt definitely has that feature. Have a look at [QWebFrame#load](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebframe.html#load-2) and [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkrequest.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this with Spynner:

```
import spynner
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager

url = "http://localhost:8080/niklas/test.php"
data = "foo=bar"
headers = { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }

req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))
for k, v in headers.items():
    req.setRawHeader(k, v)

browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.webframe.load(req, QNetworkAccessManager.PostOperation, data)
browser._wait_load()

print browser.html
```

Comment: And if we would like to `POST` one more time in the same script, what is the syntax ? If I try to run `browser.webframe.load()` one more time, I get the following error : "QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once."

Comment: @sputnick: I get this error only if I run `load` twice in a row without waiting. Did you call `_wait_load()` in between?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Spynner is based partly on Webkit. [Webkit bug 82506](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=82506) discusses this behavior.